# Invalid regular expression - Google Chrome only

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I have this regular expression to validate a username:

```
/^(?=.{5,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/
```

It works in IE, Firefox and Safari browsers, but in Chrome there is a javascript error thrown on invoking the validation.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?=.{5,20}$)(?![*.])(?!.*[*.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9.]+(?.])$/: Invalid group

I have used Expresso and regex101.com to confirm that it is a syntactically correct regex.

How do I go about finding the problem?

Comment: No, It works nowhere, lookbehind `(?<!...)` doesn't exist in javascript.

Comment: Make sure you click the "javascript flavor" on regex101. I just tested it and it fails for the reason @CasimiretHippolyte pointed out.

Comment: I wonder how you tested it in Firefox...

Comment: Not sure, this is legacy code. Doesn't throw an error in any other browsers.  Seems to validate correctly.

Comment: *"Doesn't throw an error in any other browsers."* This regular expression literal definitely throws an error in Firefox.

Comment: look behind is not supported in JavaScript

Comment: A question can be closed as offtopic due to a typo if fixing a typo solves the issue. Removing `<` in the original expression does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The lookbehind `(?<![_.])` checks if the last character is not a `_` or `.`. You can do it with a lookahead:

```
/^(?!.*[_.]$)(?=.{5,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$/
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or, you can use grouping so that `.` or `_` were always followed with alphanumerics and shorten your regex:

```
/^(?=.{5,20}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[._][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/
```

BTW, you can check the length with JS **string length** and just keep the `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[._][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/` regex. Much more readable and maintainable.

```js
var pass = "Someword234";
if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[._][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/.test(pass) && pass.length > 5 && pass.length < 20) {
    document.write("Good!");
} else {
  document.write("Bad!");
}
```

Comment: +1 Very good explanation - but I disagree about the String.length calls making it more readable. To me this makes it longer, more unreadable and probably makes it slower as well.

Comment: Answering regex related questions, there is no way to please everyone's tastes. Ones hate regex and try to do all that can be done without it without regex (there seems to be more of such people here) and others do not mind solving problems that can be solved with regex with regex only. These people are in minority here. Thus I formulated my answer according to these considerations.

Answer (score 2):

Reading your pattern it seems that you need a string:

- with only ascii letters, digits, dots and underscores
- that doesn't start or end with a dot or an underscore
- without consecutive dot or underscores
- with a length between 5 and 20 characters

In one pattern, you can write this:

```
/^(?=.{5,20}$)[A-Z0-9]+(?:[_.][A-Z0-9]+)*$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Look behid it's not supported in javascript

```
(?<!....)
```

what about trying now

```
/^(?=.{5,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?![_.])$/
```